# How to set coordinate axis in R?

Tags: r

I get a graph1.jpg with the following code,

```
x = seq(-0.25, 1.25, length = 400)
y1=x
plot(x, y1,type="l",ann=FALSE)
text(0.3,0.2,labels="y=x")
mtext("x", 1, at=1.25, line=1)
mtext("y", 2, at=1.25, line=1)
```

Please compare graph1.jpg and graph2.jpg,there are two main diffrences between them,how can i change graph1 into graph2?

1.To change the  coordinate axis in graph1 into graph2's.How to set right origin of coordinate
2.No arrow of coordinate axis in graph1
3.To make the `y` (mtext in y axis in graph1.jpg) horizontal

This is a graph1.jpg.
 [image]

This is a graph2.jpg,maybe  graph2.jpg is made by gimp.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `arrows` , `axis` and setting some `plot` parameters you can get this :

[image]

```
## you call plot without axes, without box, without axes labels
plot(x, y1,type="l",frame.plot=FALSE,
     axes=FALSE,xlab='',ylab='')
## write some text
text(0.3,0.2,labels="y=x")
text(max(x),-0.1,"x")
text(-0.1,max(x),'y')
## draw axes lines with arrows
arrows(min(x), 0, max(x), 0)
arrows(0, min(x), 0, max(x))
## add axes ticks
axis(1,at=c(0,0.5,1),pos=0)
axis(2,at=c(0,0.5,1),pos=0)
```